# deleting local modifications when replicating couchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a master couchdb, which is replicated to a local db every time the local application starts.
The user can modify the local docs, but I want these docs to be deleted when the replication starts if they have disappeared from the master db.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is already how replication works. When a document is modified (including deletion), that change gets replicated.

The only possible problem you may encounter is that if a local change is made at the same time a deletion occurs, then upon sync, there will be a conflict.

So you need your local app to do some sort of conflict resolution, which selects the deleted revision.  I suggest reading about the CouchDB [Replication and Conflict Model](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/replication/conflicts.html) as a starting place.

Comment: Ok, I get it ! Thanks